# How to format images in flexbox to avoid overflow and cropping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a responsive image gallery using flexbox where each row has images scaled to equal height while preserving aspect ratio and not cropping.

To highlight what I mean here are some placeholder images of various dimensions and the styling I tried:

```css
.art-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.art-item {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}

.art-item>img{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="art-container">
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/300x450/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x200/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'></img></div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jimby/pen/YzMwwbd)

I used `min-height: 100%` and `width: auto` to scale all the images to the height of their row while preserving aspect ratio but this results in the image overflowing past its `art-item` container so the image gets cropped.

Comment: What do you want to define as the height of a row - can it vary or is it fixed from the start?

Comment: I want it to vary. The height should be the largest height of the image the will fit in the row. This is already accomplished in the snippet I provided.

Comment: If the height of a row is to be the height of the image with the largest natural height then other images will look blurry as they stretch to fill the height. Are you sure it shouldn’t be the height off the image with the smallest natural height?

Comment: I would be open to use smallest natural height as well. The only real reason I used largest is because it seemed easier.

Comment: What constraints are there on the aspect ratios and natural heights and widths of the images? I assume you want any image to be shown at maximum with the viewport dimensions?

Comment: Right now I'm not setting any constraints on aspect ratios, width or height. I was to keep it as general as possible. How would those constraints change the core question?

Comment: What to do if the natural width and height of an image is greater than the viewports dimensions? You didn’t want overflow, but I don’t know what that means in this case.

Comment: Fair enough. For now lets assume the width and height are less than the viewport dimensions.

Comment: I think you’ll need JS to calculate which images can fit on the current line, and if there is wide variation in aspect ratios the result is going to look odd - blurry images if you go for max height and images that may be too small to show detail if you go for min height.

Comment: I was hoping there was an elegant solution using flexbox since this seems like a reasonable use case but I could always figure it out using JS. Thanks for taking the time to talk through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set an explicit height for your rows. If this height has to be dynamic you have to set it via javascript.

```css
.art-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.art-item {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 200px;
}

img{
 height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="art-container">
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/300x450/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x200/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'></img></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is define each image to take up the same height. You could give art-item for example a height of 20vw. And then tell your images to take up 100% height. And since you already have width at auto for your images. They will take up the width proportional to the new calculated height.

Comment: Cover will crop images if necessary.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly define the width of the images. I also don't want to use `object-fit: cover` as this would result in cropping.

Comment: I reread your question. My new comment will help. To clarify: You will need to set a clear height in some way for this to work. That's why I gave you vw as unit. % can work too as long as any of the parent elements have a width unit defined that translate to px.  Because since % units are relative to parent or indirectly grandparents, the parents or grandparents need to provide a computed px size reference.

Comment: Your new comment describes what I've already tried. The problem is this results in the images overflowing past their `art-item` containers, thus, they get cropped by the next `art-item` in the gallery.

Comment: No, it worked for me with your sample code. If you specify the height of art-item. And then give the images a height of 100% then they will all follow the same rule of height, which is the one u set on art-item. That causes a consistent height. Then your width auto on the images gives them the ability to freely grow their width, basically making them grow proportionally to their aspect ratio. As long as you then don't give a width on the art-item, the images will grow their width with respect to their aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you please post explicit code so I can be sure I'm not misinterpreting you? If you defined a fixed height for `art-item` like `height: 20vh` then you misinterpreted my question. I said above that I want the height to be the largest height of the image that will fit in the row, not some fixed size.

Comment: I've read all of your comments here. I see the issue. And it does seem to be more complex than it looks. I've tried to achieve the same as you now, but didn't figure it out yet. I do believe I achieved this before in the past using flexbox. I'll get back to you if I find it.

Comment: If you do figure it out please do let me know. Thank you.