# How to scale flexbox items to the size of their containing images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a responsive image gallery using flexbox where each row has images of different dimensions which are scaled to equal height while preserving aspect ratio. For example, if a row has one `100x50` image and one `100x100` image the `100x50` image should be scaled to `200x100` so both images can be placed in a row with a height of `100px`.

In other words, the page should take two images like this:

[image]

and display them like this:

[image]

I attempted to accomplish this by using `min-height: 100%` and `width: auto` on the images. The problem is when the `100x50` image is scaled to `200x100` it overflows past its `art-item` container and when the second image is placed it overlaps the first resulting in something like this:

[image: attempt]

Here is a snippet to demonstrate my attempt:

```css
.art-container {
  display: flex;
}

.art-item>img{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="art-container">
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff'></img></div>
  <div class="art-item"> <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff'></img></div>
</div>
```

I believe this could be corrected if there were a way to force `art-item` to inherit the width of its containing `img`. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: We are back to the points raised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78124007/how-to-format-images-in-flexbox-to-avoid-overflow-and-cropping you need to decide the height of a particular row for which you’ll need to do calculations on natural img dimensions using JS and beware of horrible blurriness if you double the size of an image in both directions.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there would be a work around for this simplified scenario. It seems strange to me CSS is able to do all the sizing adjustments I'm looking for but can't handle the last step of adjusting `art-item` to the width of the `img` element... Thank you for your continued help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have images in a row while keeping them a consistent height, you'll need several things. Some of these you have already, but you'll need them all:

- flexbox
- a specific height for your row of images
- images that take up 100% of the width and height of their parent containers
- and an `object-fit: cover;` to maintain the images' aspect ratio

```css
.art-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.art-item {
  /* Set to any desired height */
  height: 200px;
}

.art-item > img {
  /* 100% width and height specifications makes image fill its parent */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* Maintain aspect ratio with full fill */
}
```

```html
<div class="art-container">
  <div class="art-item">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff'>
  </div>
  <div class="art-item">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is technically a solution to what I was asking but I was hoping to avoid defining a specific height since that will vary depending on what images I use. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I figured that was the case, and I tried to come up with a solution that would avoid specifying a height at first. Unfortunately, I'm unsure if that's possible with a pure HTML/CSS solution. It will likely require introducing JavaScript into the mix.